# Cannot update a component (`Q`) while rendering a different component (`ProductCard`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an warning about update a component while rendering. I don't understand how I can solve it. I know it got's from the  because I pass two functions. The problem may be due to the ToastContainer producing toasts during rendering, and the performance of addToFavorite or deleteFromFavorite calling toast.success or toast.info. These functions may attempt to update the component's state while it is rendering, so be warned. How I can write my code right? I am new to React.

```
export const Shop = () => {
    const favoritedString = localStorage.getItem("favorited");
    const favorited = favoritedString ? JSON.parse(favoritedString) : [];
    const addToFavorite = ()=>{
        toast.success('Item added to favorite!', {
            position: "top-center",
            autoClose: 1000,
            hideProgressBar: true,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            theme: "light",
            transition: Bounce,
            });
    }
    const deleteFromFavorite = ()=>{
        toast.info('Item removed from favorite!', {
            position: "top-center",
            autoClose: 1000,
            hideProgressBar: true,
            closeOnClick: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            theme: "light",
            transition: Bounce,
            });
    }
  return (
    <div className='shop-wrapper'>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="product-cards">
                {productData.map(el=>(
            <ProductCard key={el.id} addToFavorite={addToFavorite} deleteFromFavorite={deleteFromFavorite} isFavorited={favorited.includes(el.id)} {...el}></ProductCard>
                ))}
         <ToastContainer />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

type Props = {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    img: string;
    isFavorited : boolean;
    addToFavorite: () => void; 
   deleteFromFavorite: () => void;
}
export const ProductCard = (props : Props) => {
  const [isFavorited, setIsFavorited] = useState(props.isFavorited);
  

  const addToFavorite = () => {
    setIsFavorited((prevIsFavorited) => {
      const favoritedString = localStorage.getItem('favorited');
      const favorited = favoritedString ? JSON.parse(favoritedString) : [];
      if (prevIsFavorited) {
        const updatedFavorited = favorited.filter((id) => id !== props.id);
        props.deleteFromFavorite();
        localStorage.setItem('favorited', JSON.stringify(updatedFavorited));
      } else {
        props.addToFavorite();
        const updatedFavorited = [...favorited, props.id];
        localStorage.setItem('favorited', JSON.stringify(updatedFavorited));
      }
      return !prevIsFavorited; 
    });
  };


  return (
    <div className='product-card'>
        <div className="like">
        <img onClick={addToFavorite} height={32} width={32} src={ isFavorited  ? "images/heart-like.svg" : "images/heart-unlike.svg"} alt="Like" />
        </div>
        <img src={props.img} alt="Product iamge" />
        <h3>{props.name}</h3>
        <div className='bottom-card'>
            <p>{props.category}</p>
            <p>${props.price}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Tried googling error